# IE9 - problem with placeholder and background-image in combination with gradient

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a text input field in HTML and the attribute `placeholder`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter results...">
```

Unfortunately, the `placeholder` attribute seems not to work? I thought it is implemented in Internet Explorer 9?
You can see the demo here: http://jsbin.com/esiya3/5/ - http://jsbin.com/esiya3/5/edit

Also I have a problem with `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#f0f0f0')";` in combination with a `background-image`. In all other browsers, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome, the gradient and the background-image is displayed. Only in IE 9 the background-image is not there. I have to exclude the gradient, then I can see the image. But what can I do to have both?

Here is the demo with the gradient:
http://jsbin.com/esiya3/5/ - http://jsbin.com/esiya3/5/edit

and without the gradient:
http://jsbin.com/esiya3/6/ - http://jsbin.com/esiya3/6/edit

Perhaps someone have an idea?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: IE9 is still in beta, which makes it difficult to determine what should "work".

Comment: oh, okay. But the thing with the gradient, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine a gradient filter with an alpa image loader:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myimage.png')
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f0f0f0');
```

to solve the gradient-picture problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can use svg for background-image.
you should with svg tag create your gradiant & save it with etension .svg , then load it in css file.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <linearGradient id="g">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="blue" />
<stop offset="0.3" stop-color="yellow" />
<stop offset="0.6" stop-color="orange" />
<stop offset="1" stop-color="red" />
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g)" />
</svg>
```

css file

```
div{background-image: url(gradient.svg);}
```